# How to I make my review model form show the name of the current user when rendered in template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a review form in Django. I have rendered the form, but I would like the form to display the name of the current logged in user to enable me to associate each review with a user.

**Here is my model:**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    # SET_NULL ensures that when a company is deleted, their reviews remains
    reviewers_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Reviewed By: (Your Name)')
    review_text = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Your Review: (Maximum of 200 Words)')
    rating = Int_max.IntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    date_added = models.DateField('Review Date', auto_now_add=True)
```

**Here is my view:**

```
def submit_review(request):
    form = ReviewForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            # gets the company that was immediately submitted in the review form
            company = request.POST.get('company')
            
            # gets the rating that was immediately submitted in the review form
            rating = request.POST.get('rating')
            
            # uses the name of the company submitted to instantiate the company from the Company database
            companyone = Company.objects.get(pk=company)
            
            """
            emloys companyone above to retrieve already existing average rating associated with it
            adds this to the current rating sent by the user and stores the total back to the average 
            rating field of companyone
            """
            companyone.average_rating = round((int(rating) + int(companyone.average_rating))/2)
            companyone.save()
            
            return redirect('review-submitted')
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'submit-review.html', context)
```

**Here is the form that gets rendered:**

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In template,

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <p>{{ user.get_username }} </p>
{% endif %}
```

In views,

```
request.user.get_username()
```

Comment: {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     <p>{{ user.get_username }} </p>
{% endif %}     this did the job thanks... There was no need for the views part. Thanks a lot oncemore!